# How to solve Android Compose HorizontalPager scroll problem when it has a LazyRow child?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When a LazyRow inside a Compose HorizontalPager, the pager horizontal scroll will get stuck when scroll to other page.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun PagerScreen() {
    HorizontalPager(pageCount = 2) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(
                    if (it == 0) {
                        Color.Blue
                    } else {
                        Color.Red
                    }
                )
        ) {

            Text(text = "Pager: $it", modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp), color = Color.White)

            LazyRow(contentPadding = PaddingValues(10.dp)) {
                items(12) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background), contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(10.dp)
                            .size(80.dp)
                    )
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Problem video]

I have tried the accompanist pager lib and compose neweast version 1.4.0-beta02. Both has the same problem

I want some help to fix the bug by source code of HorizontalPager.

Comment: Compose release v1.4.0, still has the problem!

Comment: @Warn ManHi Holen Zhou. The same for me at 1.5.0-beta2. Did you find solution?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet, so I'm temporarily sticking with the original approach , use ViewPager

Answer (score 1):

I reported this bug and they said that it will be fixed in 1.6 alpha release
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/287505123

Comment: That's a coincidence! I just tried it myself. The official team has fixed this issue in the latest alpha version: 1.6.0-alpha01. However, the results are not satisfactory. Although there is no more lag, the nested scrolling is still not smooth.

Comment: Alright, there is still a chance of it getting stuck, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with horizontal scroll modifier. Try disable **userScrollEnabled** so:

```
val userScrollEnabled = remember {
    derivedStateOf { 
        !scrollState.isScrollInProgress 
    }
}
```

I hope it's help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to retain the scrolling function.